# How make list of ingredients in recipes in SQLITE3 Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying make database of recipes. In the table "recipes" with col "ingredients", I would like to have a list of ingredient IDs, e.g. [2,5,7]. Can I make something like this or I should be looking for another solution?

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('recipes.db')
c = conn.cursor()


c.execute('''CREATE TABLE recipes(ID INT, name TEXT, ingredients INT)''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE ingredients(ID INT, nazwa TEXT, kcal REAL)''')
```

Another idea is to make another table (The list of ingredients) where I will have 15 cols with number of ingredients.

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE The_list_of_ingredients(ID INT, ingredient1   INT,    ingredient2 INT,    ...)''')
```

Can I connect every ingredient 1, ingredient 2 ... with their respective ingredients ID?

Comment: Can each ingredient belong to at most 1 recipe or could each ingredient belong to more than 1 recipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely looking for [a many-to-many relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) between recipes and their ingredients.

```
CREATE TABLE recipes(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE ingredients(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, kcal REAL);
CREATE TABLE recipe_ingredients(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  recipe_id INTEGER,
  ingredient_id INTEGER,
  quantity REAL,
  FOREIGN KEY(recipe_id) REFERENCES recipes(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredients(ID)
);
```

This way your data might look something like e.g.

### ingredients

| id | name | kcal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | egg | 155 |
| 2 | cream | 196 |

### recipes

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | omelette |

### recipe_ingredients

| recipe_id | ingredient_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | 100 |
| 1000 | 2 | 50 |

(assuming `kcal` is kcal per 100g, and `quantity` is in grams and a rather creamy omelette)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store id's as string

```
json.dumps(list_of_ingredients_ids)
```

But probably best solution is many to many relation